# Anatomy for a head in the middle of the neck

Tags: creature-design, anatomy

In all animals with a neck, the head is always the end of the line. But what if it were otherwise? Specifically, what anatomy would you need to change to get a head in the middle of the neck, while still letting past all of the connections required for heads further up the line

[image: Diagram]

The animal should be a tetrapod, and the heads have a humanoid-shaped cranium with the neck entering and exiting by the top and bottom

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you're asking us to brainstorm and build your creature for you. The help center is very clear that brainstorming is not permitted on this site. A user with your experience has no excuse for repeatedly ignoring policy explicitly written out like that.

Comment: Quick question: I'm all for weird creatures, but why? Did you see any advantage or benefit of this specific arrangement to justify it over , say,  having one head with a second mouth born from pharyngeal Jaws and eyes located in the neck? Or just 2 heads each with their own necks? Because real life shows us that 2 headed animals in the traditional sense of 2 heads-2 necks is something way easier to occur than whatever this is supposed to be, precisely because of how we form as embryos. This sounds more like the work of a genius mad surgeon than the result of natural evolution.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The main issues with these connections are the spine, spinal cord, and oesophagus/trachea

## Spine

The spine is easy to fix: Simply add an inverted occipital bone on top of the skull, upon which the spine starts anew. The neck muscles can simply attach to the top of the skull, perhaps with some extra attachment points grown onto the bone

## Spinal Cord

The spinal cord must stay continuous to function properly. This can be achieved by extending the brain stem past the thalami as an extra nerve cord, which should bend back to exit the extra spine's foramen magnum

## Oesophagus/Tracheae

The only way to add these features is to add a hole in the skull roof before the extra occipital bone, through which these tubes will pass. These structures will have to sit asymmetrically near side by side, so as to allow the pharynx to reach both tubes without interrupting the trachea

Comment: "simply add"? All chordata develop at hembriological level starting around a tube connecting the proto-mouth to the proto-anus. You can't simply add another end, because no organism can work going from anus to anus or from mouth to mouth.

Comment: While Stack Exchange encourages people to answer their own questions, the purpose of that encouragement is to *advance the body of information other people asking similar questions may find useful.* To that end the answer is expected to be canonical - this isn't. Worse, you should be explaining the worldbuilding process that led you to this answer: the research you did, the questions you asked yourself... IMO, this answer has no value to anyone but yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[Parasitic twin syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_twin).

Also known as fetus in fetu, occurs as a result of either: two eggs being fertilised in the womb at the same time, but fusing in such a way that one developing embryo becomes enveloped by the other, or a single embryo which splits, then re-fuses with a similar effect.

***Image not suitable for the squeamish.***

> [image]

<sup>Copyright marked, [opposingviews.com](https://www.opposingviews.com/health/baby-born-additional-head-attached-stomach), 2022, fair usage.</sup>

This could develop in a way that the secondary (lower) head develops normally, the blood vessels, spinal cord/cervical vertebrae, muscles, oesophagus and trachea fusing with the dominant offspring in the position shown by the OP's picture. The rest of the body would then be resorbed instead of fully developing.

The genetic predisposition for this could be passed on from generation to generation. An occasional throwback with but a single head might be produced, shunned as a freak and driven from the group.

Comment: I doubt that such a feature can consistently happen in a species. It might be the result of a single mishap.

Comment: FYI, it's better [not to feed the troll](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/86263/l-dutch-im-back-and-in-business#comment203621_86263) but just flag the posts/comments and move on.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I will state right off that the design we have isn't "good", it is just "what we have".

The question becomes: what functions are supported by the different "heads".  Among the functions currently supporter are:

- respiration
- vision
- hearing
- smell
- food consumption (and taste)
- thinking
- vocalization

There really isn't any reason these must be together, though sensor organs near the brain does help.

I think I could easily accept a creature with eyes moved to a higher level, for better vision.  Similarly, a mouth at a higher level, like a giraffe.

Another thing to consider: two necks.  A grazer with a low head with a mouth and a high head with eyes, respiration, and brain makes a lot of sense to me.  Such a beast could even graze underwater while watching for predators.